# How to initialize a database on a data volume container?

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, docker, flask, docker-compose

Here my simple scenario, I have a simple `Flask`app that connect to a postgres this way:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='postgresql://username:secretpassword@postgres:5432/myproj'
```

And I have a simple `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes_from:
        - data
    environment:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secretpassword
        POSTGRES_USER: username
        POSTGRES_DB: myproj
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  web:
    build: .
    volumes_from:
      - app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  data:
      image: postgres:latest
      volumes:
          - /var/lib/postgresql/data
      command: "true"
  app:
      build: .
      volumes:
          - .:/myproj
      command: "true"
```

I need to lunch a made by myself flask script, that creates the tables for my app:

```
export FLASK_APP='./myproj/__init__.py'
flask createdbs
```

I have put these 2 operation in the `Dockerfile` of my `web` service but because my service and the `postgres` service have a `depends_on` relationship, the postgres db host is not available during the building phase.

Any suggestion on the best way to achieve this ? I want to avoid hacks, I would prefer respect a correct Docker workflow.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use the "command" keyword:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/command
(look also at entrypoint keyword)

```
  web:
    build: .
    volumes_from:
      - app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    command: "export FLASK_APP='./myproj/__init__.py' && flask createdbs"
```

or using command just to launch your flask script and let your export in your dockerfile.

Note that "depends_on" only start one container before the other, but do not wait your postgres database to be ready. If you want to wait until postgres is ready to answer, you can use scripts like "wait-for-it.sh postgres:5432" that are well explained in docker-compose doc: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/